# How to find by query default catalog for current user in SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql-server

I know the statement to find default schema for user in catalog, so i need now to get default catalog for current user by a query for sql server.

Comment: [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/) and [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference) are different software packages produced by different companies. Even if both of them implement SQL, they extend it in different ways and sometimes they use different syntax conventions that render the queries incompatible between them. Please use only the tags that match the software you are using.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server, the terms "catalog" and "database" are synonymous. You can get the current login's default database with:

```
SELECT default_database_name
FROM sys.server_principals
WHERE name = ORIGINAL_LOGIN();
```

This database context is used only when a specific database context is not specified in the connection string (e.g. "Initial Catalog=" or "Database="
).

To get the current database context rather than the default database, use `DB_NAME()`:

```
SELECT DB_NAME() AS current_database;
```

Comment: this could return `master`even if you do `USE DB1`first ?

Comment: @GuidoG, this query will return the default catalog (database) associated with the login regardless of the current database context. If the login's default database is `master`, it will still return `master` even if `USE DB1;` is executed beforehand. If the requirement was to return the current database rather than default database, `SELECT DB_NAME();` would do the job.

Comment: Yes I understand now. Maybe it would be better to put the `SELECT DB_NAME()` also in your answer just to cover all cases

Comment: @GuidoG, I added `DB_NAME()` to my answer, although I'm not sure that is relevant since the question asked about the current user's default catalog rather than the current session.